# Proof of a combinatorial identity$\binom{4n}{2}-4\binom{n}{2}=\binom{4}{2}n^2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I struggle to prove the combinatorial identity:

$$\binom{4n}{2}-4\binom{n}{2}=\binom{4}{2}n^2.$$

The proof needs to be combinatorial, not algebraic.

Comment: We have four groups of $n$ things. The ways to choose two things from all $4n$ objects are...

Comment: You have four rooms, each containing $n$ people. $\binom{4n}2$ is the number of ways to choose two of these people. $\binom42$ is the number of ways to choose two rooms, and $n^2$ is the number of ways to pick one person from each of the chosen rooms, so $\binom42n^2$ is the number of ways to pick two people from different rooms. $\binom{n}2$ is the number of ways to pick two people from the same room. Now just put the pieces together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Counting one way:  We see that $$\binom{4n}{2}$$ is the number of $2$-subsets of $$\{1,2,\ldots,4n\}.$$

---

Counting another way:  We see that $$\binom{4}{2}n^2$$ is the number of is the number of $2$-subsets of $$\{1,2,\ldots,4n\}$$ whose two elements belong to different subsets in the partition $$\big\{\{1,2,\ldots,n\},\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\},\{2n+1,2n+2,\ldots,3n\},\{3n+1,3n+1,\ldots,4n\}\big\}.$$

We see that $$4\binom{n}{2}$$ is the number of is the number of $2$-subsets of $$\{1,2,\ldots,4n\}$$ whose two elements belong to the same subsets in the partition $$\big\{\{1,2,\ldots,n\},\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\},\{2n+1,2n+2,\ldots,3n\},\{3n+1,3n+1,\ldots,4n\}\big\}.$$

---

Hence $$\binom{4n}{2}=\binom{4}{2}n^2+4\binom{n}{2}.$$